# Separate the connected lines and shapes

Tags: matlab, shapes, image-recognition, overlapping, image-segmentation

I want an approach and method to separate the connected lines. Here is my image

[image]

and here is the result I would like

[image]

How do I solve that problem? Thank you in advance!

Sincerely

Comment: I tried this method using the watershed over the distance function of the connected component set to separate them like http://www.mathworks.fr/company/newsletters/articles/the-watershed-transform-strategies-for-image-segmentation.html and https://opencv-code.com/tutorials/count-and-segment-overlapping-objects-with-watershed-and-distance-transform/ . here is some results obtained http://oi39.tinypic.com/adkprk.jpg and http://oi39.tinypic.com/29e6p86.jpg ... this method is inappropriate for the shapes textelines

Answer (score 0):

The watershed would be a problem as you have shown it produces multiple segmentations of the original line. Originally the watershed works for grains due to their [convex shapes](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2013/11/19/watershed-transform-question-from-tech-support/), while here in the case of lines there is no global convex shape to cause a good fragmentation, it would be good to use the watershed with some constraints.

It would be good to try solving a simpler version of the problem. Imagine that there are only horizontal and vertical lines possible. So in this case it would mean separating the horizontal long lines by cutting the short vertical lines (length measured by projecting on the x-y gradient). The basic hint is to use the gradient/slope of these lines to help decide where to cut - orthogonal line. In the more general case the problem requires a measure of [local curvature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature#Curvature) or [geodesic distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic).

A simpler solution(in edit) is just removing the junction points in the skeleton you have.
This would cause some of your lines which are connected horizontally to be segmented but i guess this can be fixed with some end point filtering. A simple try here:

```
 J = imread('input.png');
 B = bwmorph(J,'branchpoints');
 L = bwlabel((J>0).*(~B),8); %removing the branch points from the skeleton
 Label = label2rgb(bwlabel((J>0).*(~B),8),'jet',[0 0 0]);
```

[image]

Final labeled line components. This requires further end point prefiltering, direction based filtering.

Comment: thank you for your response, I already tried it but I can detect all  branchpoints , I call bwmorph to get branchpoints. Then remove then. Then get the endpoints of the segments and compute the angle. detect any segments that are more vertical than horizontal between (pi/4 and 3pi/4). here is results obtained. but despite all I can detect all branchpoints and I can detect all connected lines here's results obtained http://oi58.tinypic.com/2463os9.jpg

Comment: I guess its better using the relative angle between segments and not directly the absolute angle subtended by the line segments. This might provide some more robustness.

Answer (score 0):

The parts of the contour that should be separated are basically the sections that are not in the same direction as most of the rest of the contour.

I can only give you a basic way to do this without specific code or functions and I doubt it is the most efficient, but since there are not too many answers here...also this is using the knowledge of the problem and the solution...

1. Find the connected contour with all its branches as a set of pixel coordinates (which represent the line as a single pixel wide contour)
2. Convert the contour list to a set of angles between each adjacent pixel coordinate
3. Optional: Filter out the high frequency components with an averaging filter
4. Histogram the angles to find the angle most of the contour lines lay on (call it the common angle)
5. Search the contour looking for sections that go from +/-common angle (tolerance of +/-30 degrees) to the negative of that (-/+ common angle with similar tolerance).
6. For each section delete the pixels associated with angles between the two thresholds above (i.e. common angle + 30 deg to -common angle - 30 degrees.
7. Repeat for each connected contour

Hope this helps some